# How to increases foreground app volume and pause background app volume in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, volume, background-foreground

I have to pause background app audio player and play some instruction in foreground app ,

**What is my scenario:**

**1) Scenario for volume increases**

In my case I have increase media volume, If volume is slow to play foreground app instruction so used below code.

```
  AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
  CGFloat volume = audioSession.outputVolume;
  NSLog(@"%.2f", volume);
  if ((volume > 0 && volume < 1) || volume == 0)
  {  
    MPVolumeView* volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] init];
    //find the volumeSlider
    UISlider* volumeViewSlider = nil;
    for (UIView *view in [volumeView subviews]){
    if ([view.class.description isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]){
      volumeViewSlider = (UISlider*)view;
       break;
     }
    }
    [volumeViewSlider setValue:1.0f animated:YES];
    [volumeViewSlider 
    sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  }
```

In this case if background app audio player is playing some music in slow volume suddenly increase volume in both app.

- Any alternative way to increases only foreground app volume.

  **2) Scenario to pause background app volume.**

If in background any other media is playing and we need to play instruction in foreground app like navigation instruction, then background media voice should be pause or lower it's volume automatically.

Please give solution on both scenarios.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?